# Intuitive reason for the continuity requirement in convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> We say that a sequence of random variable $(X_n)$ converges in
> distribution to $X$, if $F_{X_n}(x)\rightarrow F(x)$ in all points $x$
> where $F$ is continuous. F is the cumulative probability function.

I have two questions about this:

1. Why is it natural to require convergence where we have continuity?
2. Why is it natural to not require convergence if we have a discontinuity?

Comment: A nice definition for convergence of probability distributions $P_n\to P$ is: $\int gdP_n\to\int gdP$ for every bounded and continuous $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. This can be transformed into a demand only on the CDF's that are involved. Doing so we encounter the points you mention. We just have to swallow that. Natural or not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are mathematical reasons for that. If one finds them intuitive/natural, depends on one's mathematical education.

Concerning the first question: it's certainly sufficient to know the limiting cdf where it's continuous, since it's monotone increasing (i.e. can have only jumps, where it's not continuous) and right-continuous, giving its value at a discontinuity.

On the other hand, imagine $X_n=\frac1n\,\sum^n_{i=1}Y_i$, where the $Y_i$ are independent and (say) normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Then, $X_n\to0$ a.s. (strong law of large numbers), so it will also converge in distribution. But the limit cdf is discontinuous, jumping from $0$ to $1$ at $x=0$ (as it's the cdf of a constant), and due to right-continuity, $F(0)=1$. But due to symmetry, $F_{X_n}(0)=\frac12$ for all $n$, so it can't converge to $F(0)=1$, there.